# How to create ssl connections for specific operations, but still allow http for all other site operations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I have been working on a solution for this problem for about a week, but am at an impasse. I have scoured many online resources, but have not found a relevant example. From what I have read on the Internet, this type of operation should be possible. However, I have not attempted something of this nature before, so I may have some glaring misconceptions/mistakes in my approach.

Is this operational mode possible for the following system configuration? If so, please lend a helping hand.

Here is some relevant information.

System Configuration: Single Page App with many partial views (some require ssl, most do not)

1. Client: Using latest versions of AngularJS, Bootstrap, and TypeScript, plus CSS, HTML5
2. Server: Using IIS 7 and C# Web API 2.0

Thanks...

Single Page App Requirements:

1. Targeting all major operating systems for smart-phones, pads, laptops, and PCs.
2. Need to have secure communication for all member registration, login, and a few data creation operations.
3. Need non-secure http for all non-user related downloads. This represents about 99% of the total site usage/day.

Background:

1. The site works fine if I run the application using https.
2. If I disable the RequireHttps attribute in the Web API controller, the site works fine.
3. I have tried enabling CORS to no avail.
4. I do not understand why Fiddler shows a 200 return value, but my app shows a 404 error.

Fiddler Results:

HTTP      Tunnel to              www.myDomain.com:443

HTTPS     www.myDomain.com       /api/Authentication/Login?memberInfo=df... xs

1. Result is 200 for both of the above in Fiddler using IE11, Chrome, and Safari.

   - The server Web API is accessed by these browsers correctly.
   - The Web API login method returns to correct encrypted string value.
2. Firefox returns a 200 in Fiddler for Tunnel to, but does not execute the HTTPS call like the other browsers.
3. Inside my application, the callback returns a 404 error when the RequireHttps attribute annotation is used.

Relevant Code:

```
this.http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://www.myDomain.com/api/Authentication/' + "Login?memberInfo=" + $scope.base64Service.encode(memberInfo),
}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // Success code here.
}).
error(function (data, status) {
  // error code here.
  // data = “” for https with status = 404;
});

public class AuthenticationController : ApiController {
[RequireHttps]
[HttpPost]
public string Login(string memberInfo) {
    // login code here.
    return memberData;
    }
}

public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute {
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
    if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps) {
       actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) {
          ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
       };
    }
    else {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
  }
}
```

web.config file entry for CORS

**Edited, removed second domain**

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
   value="http://myDomain.com" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Edit:**

Using one domain for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and the following code for AngularJS, I have been able to get a secure tunnel connection in all browsers. I also had to add my self-signed certificate for my test server to a domain exception list for Firefox. That explains the difference, noted above, between the four browsers that I tested. Apparently, the browsers were all disallowing the request, hence the 404 error. Even though the server was returning a successful response, the browser was not making the response available to my client application.

```
smmApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);
```

Comment: Using HTTPS for only part of a page is completely useless; attackers can modify the HTTP portions to bypass HTTPS entirely.  You **must** use HTTPS everywhere, including all external scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you answer one question? With the Web API 2.0 RequireHttps attribute set, the Login method on the server cannot be called via http. Https is required; otherwise, a security error is thrown. How can a hacker bypass using https in this instance?

Comment: He can change your Javascript to send him a copy of the password, then proceed with your normal login.

Comment: Here is what I see is happening with a normal user. He/she enters their user name, password, and two other parameters for our login through an https connection. The user information is sent securely to the server. If the user info is correct, he/she gets their user information back, but he/she does not get a copy of the password back from the server. He/she gets a time expiring server-side encrypted token that has some very specific user info encoded. If this is also sent via https to the client, where is the security hole?

Comment: During the time that the browser is open, the token is sent back to the server via an https channel for sensitive user specific operations. However, if the user just downloads non-sensitive data, no encrypted channel/token is sent to the server. That is where I want to use http only. If an attacker wants to do some harm, how do they get a user password/login credentials if the entire transaction is sent through an ssl channel using tunneling and NO password is sent back to the client?

Comment: If an attacker does not already have the user password/credentials, I fail to see how he can get it with the scenario I described here. I may be missing something obvious, but I am still not connecting the dots. Thanks...

Comment: So you just have a link from HTTPS to HTTP? I see; that's fine.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot take two URLs.

Comment: So, do you have any suggestions for implementing this configuration? I cannot seem to figure out how to get the returned data, which I can view in Fiddler, into my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a single domain in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried a single domain (http://myDomain.com or https://myDomain.com) for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but the response is the same. One site that I viewed showed multiple entries, so that is why I initially included both domains. Do you know of any working example that illustrates this mode of operation?

Comment: The last comment did not display the http or https in front of the domain. I think it may have to do with the two slashes.

Comment: I found the following article from MS that seems to describe what is going on with CORS, which seems to be my issue.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api. Here is the relevant quote: If the response does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, the AJAX request fails. Specifically, the browser disallows the request. Even if the server returns a successful response, the browser does not make the response available to the client application. This appears to be what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use SSL to protect against Man in the Middle attacks. If this is the case, you can't do what you're describing.

If a request to the page is made over HTTP and a MitM attack is taking place, there is nothing preventing the attacker from altering the javascript being served to the browser so that the credential requests are proxied through a malicious server.

This is why it is important to ensure that your login form, as well as the page it posts to, are both delivered over SSL.

I promise, this isn't theoretical. If you want to use SSL at all, you must serve the entire site over SSL.

The error you're seeing seems to be a CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am concerned about MITM attacks, and you are correct, the above approach does not address this. After doing some more research, it appears that strict transport security (STS) is the way to go. However, it appears that a hybrid approach may work. According to some articles, cross-domain/cross-origin calls with AngularJS, WebApi and CORS are supported. This may allow me to use myDomain.com for http and myDomain.net for https sts. MS Bing does something similar with login.live.com. Anyway, it is worth a try.

Comment: login.live.com is vulnerable to mitm attacks if loaded over http. they should fix it, you should not model your app against it.

Comment: You are right if the initial load is over http, unless strict https sts is invoked before the first transfer, which switches the http call to https client-side. Chrome/Firefox do this for some major companies automatically in the browser, but that does not scale and is not available to smaller companies. What I am doing, and I have verified that this works, is to use https sts on myDomain.NET, which requires https for all transactions. This domain is responsible for all sensitive info. The myDomain.COM is used in tandem to download 99.9% of the site data where ALL info is public.

Comment: Here is one of many links that I looked at that summarizes the issue, which you clearly understand. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security/#disqus_thread. Since myDomain.NET is started with https sts in the client app, this is about the best option I have available. An encrypted authorization token is sent back to the myDomain.COM site, which allows users to access site download functionality using http. This token could be captured (MITM), but it does not enable access to ANY sensitive information (i.e., no sensitive data, no real vulnerability).